# File not copied (only) during upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer

## Overview

For the new version v1.9.0 of my product I created a new MSI installer. The previous version of the application is v1.7.0.

Uninstalling the old version and then installing the new version works fine.

But when I try to update the old version with the v1.9.0 installer, there is exactly one file (*NLog.dll*) missing. All other files are copied just fine.

I'm using heat.exe to create components for all the dependencies of my application. So *NLog.dll* is treated exactly in the same way as every other file, but it is the only file which shows this strange behavior.

## Log snippets for *NLog.dll* from the upgrade to v1.9.0

These are the relevant log snippets for this file.

Line 5174:

```
MSI (s) (E4:1C) [17:12:42:343]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.dll' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
```

Line 37733:

```
MSI (s) (E4:1C) [17:13:12:252]: Executing op: FileRemove(,FileName=NLog.dll,,ComponentId={53AAD98D-AFDB-4D70-ADCC-5305C3174ED5})
RemoveFiles: File: NLog.dll, Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\
MSI (s) (E4:1C) [17:13:12:260]: Verifying accessibility of file: NLog.dll
MSI (s) (E4:1C) [17:13:12:264]: Note: 1: 2318 2:  
MSI (s) (E4:1C) [17:13:12:267]: Note: 1: 2318 2:
```

Line 50386:

```
MSI (s) (E4:DC) [17:13:22:442]: Executing op: ComponentRegister(ComponentId={D4B31A07-4F5F-4DAA-8280-9A782110477A},KeyPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.dll,State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=2,BinaryType=0)
1: {C2F509F4-A1F9-4377-89FE-59B4DB664FB7} 2: {D4B31A07-4F5F-4DAA-8280-9A782110477A} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.dll 
MSI (s) (E4:DC) [17:13:22:442]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.dll' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
```

## Log snippets for some other file from the upgrade to v1.9.0

For comparison, here are the log snippets for some random other file (*NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll*) which updates as expected.

Line 5173:

```
MSI (s) (E4:1C) [17:12:42:342]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
```

Line 37738:

```
MSI (s) (E4:1C) [17:13:12:267]: Executing op: FileRemove(,FileName=NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll,,ComponentId={2CE3E451-CBCA-4D6A-953A-0EEC1F23FE33})
RemoveFiles: File: NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll, Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\
MSI (s) (E4:1C) [17:13:12:269]: Verifying accessibility of file: NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll
MSI (s) (E4:1C) [17:13:12:272]: Note: 1: 2318 2:  
MSI (s) (E4:1C) [17:13:12:276]: Note: 1: 2318 2:
```

Line 50389:

```
MSI (s) (E4:DC) [17:13:22:442]: Executing op: ComponentRegister(ComponentId={0DFB8E8D-FD31-430F-A84B-C21D7BCB296B},KeyPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll,State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=2,BinaryType=0)
1: {C2F509F4-A1F9-4377-89FE-59B4DB664FB7} 2: {0DFB8E8D-FD31-430F-A84B-C21D7BCB296B} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll 
MSI (s) (E4:DC) [17:13:22:442]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
```

Line 51640:

```
MSI (s) (E4:DC) [17:13:23:148]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=c7dqtb1j.dll|NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll,SourceCabKey=filC5C20BE40C004EEC9809A0196347239A,DestName=NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll,Attributes=512,FileSize=24064,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,Version=1.3.0.804,Language=0,InstallMode=58982400,,,,,,,)
MSI (s) (E4:DC) [17:13:23:149]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll;    To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (E4:DC) [17:13:23:149]: Source for file 'filC5C20BE40C004EEC9809A0196347239A' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\,  Size: 24064
```

## Analysis of the log snippets

As you can see, the first three snippets look pretty much the same for *NLog.dll* and other files. But the last part, where the file is actually being copied, is just missing in the case of *NLog.dll*.

There is nothing in the log which would explain (to me) why *NLog.dll* is not being copied.

## Log snippets of the original v1.7.0 install

I don't know if this is relevant in any way, but here are the related log snippets for these two files from the original install. Maybe these matter because of the Ids they had during the original install.

Line 5316 (*NLog.dll*):

```
MSI (s) (E4:94) [17:11:14:734]: Executing op: ComponentRegister(ComponentId={53AAD98D-AFDB-4D70-ADCC-5305C3174ED5},KeyPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.dll,State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=0,BinaryType=0)
1: {D6410853-B366-4D05-A1A3-93FC3EFF982A} 2: {53AAD98D-AFDB-4D70-ADCC-5305C3174ED5} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.dll 
MSI (s) (E4:94) [17:11:14:734]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.dll' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
```

Line 5319 (*NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll*):

```
MSI (s) (E4:94) [17:11:14:734]: Executing op: ComponentRegister(ComponentId={2CE3E451-CBCA-4D6A-953A-0EEC1F23FE33},KeyPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll,State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=0,BinaryType=0)
1: {D6410853-B366-4D05-A1A3-93FC3EFF982A} 2: {2CE3E451-CBCA-4D6A-953A-0EEC1F23FE33} 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll 
MSI (s) (E4:94) [17:11:14:735]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll' folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
```

Line 19183 (*NLog.dll*):

```
MSI (s) (E4:94) [17:11:17:881]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=NLog.dll,SourceCabKey=fil3052FED1115C64C0B25CEB4ED20F217C,DestName=NLog.dll,Attributes=512,FileSize=422400,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,Version=5.0.0.0,Language=0,InstallMode=58982400,,,,,,,)
MSI (s) (E4:94) [17:11:17:882]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.dll;   To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (E4:94) [17:11:17:882]: Source for file 'fil3052FED1115C64C0B25CEB4ED20F217C' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: NLog.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\,  Size: 422400
```

Line 31615 (*NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll*):

```
MSI (s) (E4:94) [17:11:22:509]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=c7dqtb1j.dll|NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll,SourceCabKey=filC5C20BE40C004EEC9809A0196347239A,DestName=NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll,Attributes=512,FileSize=8704,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,Version=1.0.0.0,Language=0,InstallMode=58982400,,,,,,,)
MSI (s) (E4:94) [17:11:22:509]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll;    To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (E4:94) [17:11:22:509]: Source for file 'filC5C20BE40C004EEC9809A0196347239A' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\DiagnosticBridge\bin\,  Size: 8704
```

## Some relevant configuration snippets

For gathering the dependencies, I run *heat.exe* like this:

```
"%WIX%\bin\heat" dir "$(ProjectDir)\obj\PublishOutput" -dr BinFolder -ke -srd -sreg -cg MyComponentGroup -var var.TempPublishDir -gg -out "$(ProjectDir)\obj\MyContent.wxs"
```

The resulting components then look like this:

```
<Component Id="cmpE15B2B75697ADA78CA21A063FF464A7F" Directory="BinFolder" Guid="{876C7C40-4FD9-464E-9282-5CE83B56C4C9}">
    <File Id="fil3052FED1115C64C0B25CEB4ED20F217C" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.TempPublishDir)\NLog.dll" />
</Component>
<Component Id="cmpF5B8522DF5AB91BD2DBBA73CBCD944B8" Directory="BinFolder" Guid="{EFB396C4-4F10-4C1B-92FB-75D5C616A708}">
    <File Id="filC5C20BE40C004EEC9809A0196347239A" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.TempPublishDir)\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll" />
</Component>
```

And the relevant part of the product definition:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <Product Id="*" Name="xxx" Language="1033" Version="1.9.0.0" Manufacturer="xxx" UpgradeCode="ab9f8a5a-aa60-4327-9299-3f928136a6e4">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

## Things I've considered

- There is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760094/file-missing-after-upgrade). The important thing seems to to be to execute `RemoveExistingProducts` as early as possible. If I understand [this](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html) correctly, using the `MajorUpgrade` directive (which I use), defaults to executing `RemoveExistingProducts` very early. So I think I should be safe here.
- Also I tried running [heat.exe](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html) with the `-ag` parameter instead of `-gg`. That changes the Guid of all components to `"*"`. But it didn't make any difference.
- One thing I did notice on line 9003 of the upgrade log is this: `MSI (s) (E4:1C) [17:12:46:123]: Skipping RemoveExistingProducts action: current configuration is maintenance mode or an uninstall`. Maybe this indicates some potential problem. But when I look at the actual bin folder of my application during the upgrade, I can clearly see that first all files are being deleted, and then I can see how the folder gets populated again (but not with *NLog.dll*).

All of this would not really explain why the upgrade works fine for all other files, but not for one. Also I have deployed several previous versions of my product with a similar installer, and I never had this problem before.

Comment: Can you put the full upgrade logs on pastebin or something where I can take a quick look?

Comment: Hi Brian. I uploaded the update log here: https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/IeYXz25KkKKogvP
Your willingness to help is greatly appreciated! I'm running out of ideas...
Let me know if you also need the log of the original v1.7.0 install.

Comment: Didn't read too closely, but are you live with this second version? If not, could you compile that file with a higher version number? It is also possible to modify the version number by opening the file as a resource as well - less than ideal. I would make an [administrative image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751980/129130) of both setup and compare version info. Where in the InstallExecuteSequence is RemoveExistingProducts located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial hint for solving this problem came from Bob Arnson:

> You're trying to downgrade the version of NLog.dll. There's a bug in MSI that causes the file to be removed and not reinstalled.

And indeed, the newest version of my software references an older version of *NLog.dll* than the previous version of my software.

*NLog.dll* is actually an indirect dependency of my software. I'm referencing *NLog.Web.AspNetCore.dll* which in turn references *NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll* and *NLog.dll*, so I did not even realize that there was a version downgrade of *NLog.dll*.

Forcing customers to uninstall/reinstall was not an option. But I found a solution [here](http://howdididothatthingagain.blogspot.com/2015/07/wix-and-msi-installers-downgrade.html).

I created the following XSL transform which removes the three individual NLog components from the heat output, and instead inserts a new component which includes all three files, and where KeyPath is set on the file which I reference directly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl wix">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Remove individual components for NLog files and add the files in a single component, see CT-1886 -->
  <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765707/how-to-exclude-files-in-wix-toolset -->
  <xsl:key name="NLogFilesToRemove" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'NLog.dll') or contains(wix:File/@Source, 'NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll') or contains(wix:File/@Source, 'NLog.Web.AspNetCore.dll')]" use="@Id" />
  <xsl:template match="*[self::wix:Component or self::wix:ComponentRef][key('NLogFilesToRemove', @Id)]" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentGroup">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <Component Id="cmpBundledNLog" Directory="BinFolder" Guid="0d590e51-18bd-455a-9edf-c4ff34cce42e">
        <File Id="fileNLogDll" KeyPath="no" Source="$(var.TempPublishDir)\NLog.dll" />
        <File Id="fileNLogExtensionsLoggingDll" KeyPath="no" Source="$(var.TempPublishDir)\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll" />
        <File Id="fileNLogWebAspNetCoreDll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.TempPublishDir)\NLog.Web.AspNetCore.dll" />
      </Component>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm not sure about the complications this will create in the future (at some point I'd like to get rid of this workaround), but for now it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to downgrade the version of NLog.dll. There's a bug in MSI that causes the file to be removed and not reinstalled. The only workaround is to uninstall completely and then reinstall.

Comment: We want to avoid forcing customer to do a uninstall/reinstall. But your hint was extremely helpful for understanding what the actual problem is. I will present my solution in a separate answer. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: That's not a bug, it's a configuration. What you're describing is the default behavior of MSI, but you can change that by explicitly specifying the REINSTALLMODE property.
Adding this line: `<Property Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="dmus"/>` to the product section of your main wix file will allow for downgrades.

Comment: If not a bug, it's an odd and unexpected default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to downgrade NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll
This is not allowed by the default configuration of MSI, however you can overwrite that by explicitly specifying the [REINSTALLMODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/reinstallmode) of your istaller.

This can be achieved by overwriting the respective property in the product section of your main wix file to allow for downgrades

```
<Product Id="*"
       Name="MY SOFTWARE $(var.Version) $(var.Platform)"
       Language="1033"
       Version="$(var.Version)"
       Manufacturer="The Umbrela Corporation"
       UpgradeCode="someguid-guid-guid-guid-someguid">
...   
<Property Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="dmus"/>
...
```

Comment: I don't know why you copped a downvote.  The answer was a lifesaver for me - fixed a disappearing FSharp.Core.dll during upgrades.  The default value by the way is "omus", and by changing to "dmus" one is only changing one behaviour so it's not that radical a change.

Comment: @Kit I don't understand either, as the person who down-voted didn't explain his decision. 
All I can say is that we've been using this in the field for over an year now and haven't had any problem with it.